# Retrieve latest record added to AWS Dynamodb table and display on flask webpage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am developing a flask website where the I need to retrieve the latest record added to AWS dynamodb table and display the retrieved data on a webpage.

The primary key in my DynamoDB table is timestamp. However to query the record I am using the current date only. 'currentdate' column is not primary key.

The following is the query I have implemented:

```
 timestamp1 = datetime.datetime.now()
 timestamp = timestamp1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
 table = DynamoDB. Table('smart Irrigation')
      response = table. Scan(
            FilterExpression=Attr('currentdate').eq(timestamp),
            ScanIndexForward=False, Limit=1

        )
```

However when executing the above query, I am getting the following error message :

> ParamValidationError botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError:
> Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input:
> "ScanIndexForward", must be one of: TableName, IndexName,
> AttributesToGet, Limit, Select, ScanFilter, ConditionalOperator,
> ExclusiveStartKey, ReturnConsumedCapacity, TotalSegments, Segment,
> ProjectionExpression, FilterExpression, ExpressionAttributeNames,
> ExpressionAttributeValues, ConsistentRead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite its name `ScanIndexForward` is not applicable for `Scan` API.

They way your data is modeled leaves it very difficult to read your data in the desired way. You should consider remodelling your data.

Depending on your throughput needs I would use a GSI with a static value as partition key and `currentdate` as the sort key. That would allow you do so a `Query` on the index with `ScanIndexForward=False` and `Limit=1` which would return you the latest item.

Comment: Could you please advise me on how I should remodel my data.

Comment: I created a GSI with the currentdate as partition key and timestamp as sort key and it worked. I am now able to query with ScanIndexForward=False and Limit=1 which returns the latest item added to Dynamodb table and it is displayed on the flask webpage. Thank you so much!!!